# Download Video File via video URL in windows phone 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, video, windows-phone-8.1, media, download

I have tried to download video file from video URL. Video file created but downloading does not happen here. just 57KB file generate. My code is here.

```
   public async void DownloadTrack(Uri SongUri, string fileName)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var data = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(SongUri);


            StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.VideosLibrary;
            var file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
               ///////////////////
          using (var targetStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                await targetStream.AsStreamForWrite().WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                await targetStream.FlushAsync();
            }




        }
    }
```

Here video file creates but does not file download. I want to download file. I searched much about this. here is accepted Stackoverflow answer link but this also does the same. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812827/c-sharp-downloading-and-using-file-causes-system-unauthorizedaccessexception)

can you please provide any better solution.

Comment: You got 57KB so downloading occurred.  Do you mean that it didn't automatically play?

Comment: This didn't automatically play in Media Element and not download. that file is not 57KB file. I need to download full file from that URL

Comment: can you please help me out from this issue.?

Comment: Still don't understand if file actually got downloaded.  If it did get dowloaded can you play manually without your application?

Comment: File does not download completely. I tried to open manually but error display that this video can't be played.    actually file does not download completely.